# Section have a margin bottom and top of 100px

Tags: html, css

What i want to accomplish is that i want my section to have a margin of 100px(top and bottom) but my footer doesn't seem to respect that. Also I'd like an explanation due to me being really new to this.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 10px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#showtime {
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  z-index: 8;
}

#showtime img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


/*Image Repz*/

.showright {
  clear: both;
}

.highlight {
  font-size: 125%;
  color: blue;
}

.showright img {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.boxes:first-child {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.boxes:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.showright>p,
.showright>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.showleft img {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.showleft>p,
.showleft>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 120px;
  z-index: 6;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.d-inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Photography | Home </title>
  <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="d-inline-flex">
      <div id="branding">
        <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
      </div>
      <nav id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="PhotoGallery.html">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="VideoGallery.html">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <a href="#">LOGIN</a>
  </header>
  <section id="showtime">
    <div class="showleft boxes">
      <h2>What are we about?</h2>
      <p>In Mukhtar Photography, we specialise in creating a perfect video with the highest quality and we always tend to keep our promise. Whether it is an Video or not we are <span class="highlight">MASTERS</span> at delivering the best photos
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="showleft boxes">
      <h2>Why should you ask Mukhtar Photography for like: Weddings, videos?</h2>
      <p>Because we put our dedication towards and is very unlikely to be any cancels to the project and if there is you will be paid 90% of the money you gave us.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an oft asked question regarding "margin collapse" and is answered throughout SO and the internet. Please search for that term here or Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Your header has `position: fixed` - you need to add at least `top: 0` to fix it tt the top of the window. And add a z-index higher that those of elements, which are supposed to stax behind it.

2.) Your section has `position: relative`. In this case, the `top: 110px` just causes it to be moved down 110px, but its original space will be preserved. So it will overlap what comes below it. To fix that, use `margin-top: 110px" instead. In combination with your existing`margin: 0 auto`that adds up to`margin: 110px auto 0 auto;`If you want a bottom margin, add that too. Then it's enough to write the shorthand`margin: 110px auto;`

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 10px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 100;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#showtime {
  position: relative;
  margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  z-index: 8;
}

#showtime img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


/*Image Repz*/

.showright {
  clear: both;
}

.highlight {
  font-size: 125%;
  color: blue;
}

.showright img {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.boxes:first-child {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.boxes:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.showright>p,
.showright>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.showleft img {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.showleft>p,
.showleft>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 120px;
  z-index: 6;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.d-inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Photography | Home </title>
  <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="d-inline-flex">
      <div id="branding">
        <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
      </div>
      <nav id="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="PhotoGallery.html">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="VideoGallery.html">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <a href="#">LOGIN</a>
  </header>
  <section id="showtime">
    <div class="showleft boxes">
      <h2>What are we about?</h2>
      <p>In Mukhtar Photography, we specialise in creating a perfect video with the highest quality and we always tend to keep our promise. Whether it is an Video or not we are <span class="highlight">MASTERS</span> at delivering the best photos
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="showleft boxes">
      <h2>Why should you ask Mukhtar Photography for like: Weddings, videos?</h2>
      <p>Because we put our dedication towards and is very unlikely to be any cancels to the project and if there is you will be paid 90% of the money you gave us.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
Position: relative;
```

form #showtime element, because you have set the position to relative and has given top property some value i.e. 100px, it is taken out of the flow and place 100px away from top; that's why footer is not respecting it.